# "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" while removing some objects from a list

Tags: java

I need to delete some objects from a list if they meet a condition.

But I am getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Here is my code:

```
collegeList.addAll(CollegeManager.findByCollegeID(stateCode, districtCode));

for(College clg:collegeList){
    if(!clg.approve()){
        collegeList.remove(clg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use an iterator here

Comment: @ruchi Just take some time and effort to search SO before you post such questions. There are plenty of good answers to that on SO already - For e.g. - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection?rq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't remove elements while iterating through them in that manner.  Use an `Iterator` instead.

```
Iterator<College> iter = collegeList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    College clg = iter.next();
    if(!clg.approve()) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `Iterator` to iterate through `List` and remove objects using `Iterator#remove()`.